# How to handle double click event on kendo grid using angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I am trying to handle double click event for each row on kendo grid.Single click event is working by using k-on-change( k-on-change="methodname(dataItem.val)" ) ,  but i can not handle double click event from angularjs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get access to the element.

**HTML**

```
<div data-kendo-grid="grid" options="gridOptions"></div>
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){
    if (widget === $scope.grid) {
      $scope.grid.element.on('dblclick', function (e) {console.log(e)});
    }
  });
```